# Why my UIScreen mainScreen bounds size return 480 in ios6

Tags: height, screen, ios6

Here is my code to get main screen size

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

And in ios5 and ios6 it's return 480 of height,but when I run it in retina 4 inch simulator

,it still return 480 of height.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add a new default png photo with 1136 height.

[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size will return new height of 4-inch screen.

Comment: That strange! What's the real API for getting the screen size without depending on any resources/ios version/device.

Comment: Is there any solution for this other than adding default.png? because i am not getting exact size in iphone 6 and 6plus.

Comment: adding a 2*2 or any resolution image named "Default-568h.png"  will do the magic.

Answer (score 13):

You have to add the iPhone 5 Launch image (Default-568h@2x.png) to your project.

The 568 point tall launch image tells iOS to launch your app in 4" mode. If you don't have this image, your app is treated as a 3.5" app. Even if it is 4" compatible.

Comment: +1000 for the answer.. I spent 4 hours but was unsuccessful.. changed Default.png to Default-568h@2x.png.. worked like a charm.. thanks a lot

Comment: My experience: if you use image assets, be sure not only add Default-568h@2x.png (the name should be exactly the same) to asset, but to the project as well.

Answer (score 3):

GO to Target -> General -> Launch Images -> (Select) LaunchImages

Clear your App and Run it.

if you have splash screen select those on Launch Images.